# Antd expandable table, expand all rows at same time when click on expand button

Tags: next.js, antd, expandable-table

I'm using an expandable table from antd design version 4.10 in my app with Next.js v10.0.4. When I clicked in `+` button in table its suppose to open only the row which is selected but I don't know why it is opening all the rows at same time.

This is my table component:

```
<Table
    size="small"
    dataSource={data}
    columns={updateColumns}
    expandable={{
      expandedRowRender: (record) => (
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
      ),
      rowExpandable: (record) => record.level !== "3",
      onExpand: (expanded, record) =>
        console.log("onExpand: ", record, expanded),
    }}
  />
```

Is exactly the same code as documentation in antd design: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a `key` field for each record in your data.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr that's right, the key was missing, I added rowkey={(record) => record.stationId} to my Table component and now is working prefectly, thanxs.

Answer (score 17):

You need a `key` property for each record in your data. If you have no `key` property, you can specified it on `<Table>` component using `rowKey` prop

```
<Table rowKey="your_data_id" />
```

Comment: Nash like I said to @Scratch'N'Purr you are rifht, the key was missing, tanks.

Comment: for me it had to look like this: ```<Table rowkey={(record) => record.key} />``` and also loop through the rows of my data and assign a unique ```key```.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the table, I issue is not the code but your data. For the table work you need to add a "key" to every set of json data that you are giving to the table .
Example:
[
{
"key": 1,
"name": "hello",
"surname": "world"
},
{
"key": 2,
"name": "hello",
"surname": "world"
}
]

Comment: actually, in my case, the parent table keys not accepted by rowKey attribute. so I had to set the keys to each column. I added keys to column definition and each column of data source. I used this reply to understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This probably due to missing `key`s in your `dataSource` array which is fed into the Table, which can be verified by a message in the DevTools console saying smth about missing key.